# How to add two tab layout in single layout as shown in image

Tags: android

Here i written code but after viewpager it doesnt display second tablayout please help
Thank You Very Much in advance

there is one slider 
after that tablayout after that viewpager

Thanks in advance

and after viewpager i again want to add new tablayout

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTextDisable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Men Casual Shirts"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Men Jeans"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the image

Comment: try using width as `wrap_content` for tabitems

Comment: share the image or ask the question carefully.